# RS485 over CAN: when and why?

Tags: can, rs485, bus

I'm designing my own home automation gateway and I've already added a rs485 transceiver, everything is fine, but I'm thinking about adding also a CAN bus transceiver because I've seen that it's often used in long communication buses and many embedded electronics devices supports it.

My question is about this bus...it can be a good idea to integrate it? It will replace the RS485 in the years? It's a good equivalent replacement in term of reliability?

Comment: Both of them are pretty old. I don't think one will replace the other any time soon.

Comment: Both are robust. I'd stick with one or the other, but not both (separately.) And especially not both concurrently (over the same set of wires, protocol.) The marketplace is already littered with tons of "custom" implementations of standard bus topologies, like Profibus (485), Profinet (Ethernet), the ARINC debacle (Manchester encoding), etc.

Comment: So, what you recommend? @user253751

Comment: I think answer to your question is opinion based. Use a bus that suits your purposes. What research have you done before asking? There's many white papers comparing the buses and which one is better depending on the environment and use case.

Comment: CAN has been designed for use in vehicles while RS485 is desgned for long distance communication, up to one mile. It doesn't mean CAN won;t work in a house, but RS485 may be better adapted. In a house you have much longer distances than in a car and the environment is radically different.

Comment: The general trend even in automation is that CAN is (_slowly_) replacing RS485, or rather that CANopen is replacing Profibus. The main reason RS485 lives on isn't technical, but because it's adored by Siemens. It is true however that RS485 is more suitable than classic CAN for higher baudrates > 1Mbps.

Comment: If you want something "future proof" then CAN-FD is probably a good bet. You can usually use CAN-FD controllers/transceivers for classic CAN, so it should mostly be backwards compatible in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

Both are good for large distributed systems.

RS485 is more flexible in terms of length and speed, but its just a physical layer, so you need do choose a protocol on top

CAN is both - physical layer and protocol - with the physical layer to have some options. CAN is designed for die hard realtime in cars's. For CAN you need a µC which includes a CAN Controller. for RS485 a simple URAT is enough

You can choose any of both for home-automation... you will hardly get to the limits